# Prove that a stochastic process cannot have continuous paths

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following problem.

> Suppose that a stochastic process $V$ satisfies the conditions below
>
> - $t_1 \neq t_2$ implies that $V(t_1)$ and $V(t_2)$ are independent.
> - $\{V(t)\}$ is stationary, i.e. the (joint) distribution of $\{V(t_1+t),\dots,V(t_k+t)\}$ does not depend on $t$.
> - $\mathbb{E}[V(t)] = 0$ for all $t$.
>
> Prove that $V(t)$ cannot have continuous paths.

The hint says to consider $E[|V(t,N)-V(s,N)|^2]$ where
$$
V(t,N) = \max\{-N,\min\{N,V(t)\}\}, \quad N=1,2,3,\dots
$$
I don't see how this hint helps to prove that $V$ cannot have continuous paths. The only connection I found is the Kolmogorov's continuity Theorem.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: The case when each $X_t$ is non-random shows that the converse is not true since  a continuous function need not satisfy a Lipschitz condition of any order.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes I knew that for a fact, thanks for your reminding! I guess then the hint may indicate some other theorems that I can't recall right now.

Comment: This is false: Take $V(t) = 0$ for all $t$ (surely).

Comment: Nevertheless the problem likely wants you to assume $Var(V(t))=\sigma^2>0$ for all $t$.  Then it wants you to use the bounded convergence theorem, or some such convergence theorem, to show that if you assume continuity (with prob 1) at $s$, you can exchange limits and expectations of $\lim_{t\rightarrow s} E[(V(t,N) - V(s,N))^2]$.

Comment: @Michael We may assume that $V$ is nonzero, since it represents the white noise in the original context.

Comment: @Michael Oh I see, so you are saying that the exchange may result in a contradiction?

Comment: Yes, the exchange results in a contradiction. You can directly compute the expectation involved.  I recommend temporarily ignoring the max/min with $N$ and just directly computing $E[(V(t)-V(s))^2]$, assuming finite but nonzero variance for $V(t)$.  You can compute $E[(V(t,N)-V(s,N))^2]$ similarly.  It seems to me that the main reason for doing the projection to the set $[-N,N]$ is to allow cases where the variance of $V(t)$ can be infinite.

Comment: @Michael Thank you!! Your comment is really useful!!